# Trying to get MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI to find image that I think is there; I am using MediaScannerConnection and it finds it

Tags: java, android, mediastore, android-mediascanner

I'm trying to get a file to be recognized, which is to test my other code. Here is my code for finding the file and making sure the file is found:

```
String filePath = "/sdcard/Download/"+ fileName;
        File file = new File(filePath);
        if(file.exists()) {
            // Now scan it
            final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
                    myContext,
                    new String[]{filePath},
                    null,
                    new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                            if (uri == null) {
                                android.util.Log.d(TAG, "Scan failed or file was not added: " + path);
                            } else {
                                android.util.Log.d(TAG, "File scanned and found at: " + uri.toString());
                            }
                            latch.countDown();
                        }
                    }
            );
            android.util.Log.d(TAG, "Sanity Check- file exists at "+filePath);
            try {
                latch.await(); // This will make the current thread wait until latch count becomes 0
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            android.util.Log.d(TAG, "File does not exist: " + filePath);
        }

        if (myContext != null) {
            Cursor cursor = myContext.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
            android.util.Log.d(TAG, "Check cursor != null");
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                android.util.Log.d(TAG, "cursor is not null");

                do {
                    android.util.Log.d(TAG, "Inside cursor.moveToNext while loop");
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
                    if (columnIndex != -1) {
                        String displayName = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                        android.util.Log.d(TAG, displayName);
                    } else {
                        android.util.Log.d(TAG, "DISPLAY_NAME column not found");
                    }

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                cursor.close();
            }
            else
            {
                android.util.Log.d(TAG, "cursor is null");
            }
```

So, when it runs this code, it says the file exists at the top, so mediascanner runs, mediascanner finds the file (great), then it waits for mediascanner to finish so the results are apparent to the rest of the software, then when it gets to the bottom half of the code above, it doesn't find any files at all.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `"File scanned and found at: " + uri.toString()` Please tell the value of uri.toString().

Comment: Do not use latch.await(). Instead call the following code there where you receive the uri.

Comment: `trying to get a file to be recognized` You mean: trying to get my file scanned/indexed by the media store.

Comment: Also use file.canRead() before you try to scan.

Comment: "File scanned and found at: content://media/external_primary/images/media/1000000035"

Comment: "Do not use latch.await(). Instead call the following code there where you receive the uri." I don't quite follow you here.  I can't save the uri inside onScanCompleted, (I just tried that)... maybe if you posted an answer with the code modified the way you think it needs to be modified?  This comment is hard for me to understand.

Comment: I don't know exactly how I solved this problem, but the problem is now solved.  Thanks @blackapps for your assistance.